# Get MonoGame working on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi, monogame, opentk

this is my first post here in the pi forums. My pi arrived yesterday, and i am really exited to get my Application running on the pi.

i want to do the following ... i want to make a simple Playlist with the current songs in the playlist. just the covers of the first 4 songs should be shown. I have this already done in VB.Net using XNA. I tried to port it to monogame, with an `GraphicsModeException` of OpenTK when running on the PI.

Even a small `"Hello World"` string rendering is failing with the same exception. All is done via simple spritebatch rendering

Any suggestions ?

Edit : Source and Error 
 Source : https://bitbucket.org/S3NS4Ti0N/coverflow-test

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContext ---> System.PlatformNotSupport                                                 edException: Please, refer to http://www.opentk.com for more information.
  at OpenTK.Platform.Factory+UnsupportedPlatform.CreateGetCurrentGraphicsContext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContext..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at CoverFlow.Game1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at CoverFlow.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContext ---> System.Plat                                                 formNotSupportedException: Please, refer to http://www.opentk.com for more information.
  at OpenTK.Platform.Factory+UnsupportedPlatform.CreateGetCurrentGraphicsContext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContext..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at CoverFlow.Game1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at CoverFlow.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Yes, please share the code you're trying, along with the applicable errors/exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono only supports softfloat mode, while most RPi OSes default to hardfloat. [hardfloat support is scheduled for the next mono release I believe](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=466363). If you build the mono source from the git repo, you can get this now.